# Linq/C#: Selecting and summing items from the result of a group by?

Tags: c#, linq, select, group-by, where-clause

I have a list like this:

```
City   Total
Sydney 11
Dublin 9
London 12
Dublin 3
London 9
Sydney 12
```

I first of all need to Group By City & Sum Total so I have

```
Sydney 23
Dublin 12
London 21
```

Next I need to filter for those that entries where the total is > 20

```
Sydney 23
London 21
```

And what I finally need is the total of these entries, e.g. 44

I really want to do it in 1 single LINQ statement, possible?

Thx,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int cityTotals = cities
    .GroupBy(c => c.City)
    .Select(grp => new { City = grp.Key, Total = grp.Sum(c => c.Total) })
    .Where(c => c.Total > 20)
    .Sum(c => c.Total);
```

Comment: Nice and correct but why reuse the 'c' name in the group part? I think `.Where(g => ..).Sum(g => ...)` is so much clearer.

Answer (score 6):

A couple of alternative approaches to Lee's:

```
int cityTotals = cities
    .GroupBy(c => c.City)
    .Select(grp => grp.Sum(c => c.Total))
    .Where(total => total > 20)
    .Sum();
```

or

```
int cityTotals = cities
    .GroupBy(c => c.City, (key, grp) => grp.Sum(x => x.Total))
    .Where(total => total > 20)
    .Sum();
```